# How do I disable the app switcher on Pixel 3?

Tags: applications, google-pixel, nova-launcher, gestures

I'd like to disable fast app switching on pixel 3. My device is not rooted and I use nova launched.

I've looked through the settings and I've looked at the gestures folder and the nova launcher settings and I haven't found a feature that appears to do the trick.

Can you help me understand how I can get rid of the fast app switcher in pixel 3?

There are two things that I'm trying to stop

1- When you swipe up from the bottom of the screen and you see apps and can switch between them

2- When you swipe horizontally on the dock bar and it takes you to the most recent app

Comment: Um, don't use the Android 9/10 gestures? You should be able to revert to the classic nav keys from Settings - System - Gestures.

Comment: That seems a bit brute force

Comment: The app switcher is part of the Pixel Launcher, however since Android 10 if you disable it you'll get no app switcher at all. There is a separate build target (`SystemUiWithLegacyRecents`) that brings back the "card" recents, but that's only accessible to whoever building their own images, and seems to disable gestures altogether.